# regular expression help which includes "." in word separation

Tags: python, regex

```
expr = "name + partner_id.country_id.name + city + '  ' + 123 + '123' + 12*2/58%45"

print re.findall('\w+[.]',expr)
['name',
 'partner_id',
 'country_id',
 'name',
 'city',
 '123',
 '123',
 '12',
 '2',
 '58',
 '45']
```

I want to include "." so result should be like

```
['name',
 'partner_id.country_id.name',
 'city',
 '123',
 '123',
 '12',
 '2',
 '58',
 '45']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the regex:

```
[\w.]+
```

Explanation:

- `[...]` is the char class
- `\w` is a char of a word, short for
  `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `.` is generally a meta char to match
  any char but inside a char class its
  treated as a literal `.`
- `+` for one or more

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
re.findall('[\w.]+',expr)
```

This finds blocks of characters made of letters, numbers, underscores and dots.

Your original regex finds a word followed by a single dot, so I don't see how you got the posted results: http://codepad.org/Khsd6IuW .

Comment: +1 for pointing the original regex did not produce the shown result.